# Greek letter in title of R Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to include a Greek letter in the title of R markdown document?

I tried this:

```
---
title: "α-Amylase"
author: "author"
date: "8 March 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document:
  keep_tex: true
toc: yes
toc_depth: 6
---
```

And this:

```
---
title: "$\alpha$-Amylase"
author: "author"
date: "8 March 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document:
  keep_tex: true
toc: yes
toc_depth: 6
---
```

Comment: What happens when you do that? knit to html worked with your first example.

Comment: ??-Amylase
author
8 March 2017

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, with html it gives the following output:

```
---
title: \(\alpha\)-Amylase
author: "author"
date: "8 March 2017"
output: html_document
toc: yes
toc_depth: 6
---
```

[image]