# Non English characters in ggplot within a knitr document

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I'm trying to knit to pdf a file with Lithuanian characters like ąčęėįšųž in RStudio from .Rmd file. While knitting to html works properly and the `ggplot` title has the Lithuanian characters, when knitting to pdf `ggplot` does create warnings and dismisses these characters.

Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header_lt_text.txt
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
```


## Lithuanian char: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪžąčęėįšųūž
```{r}
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+
    geom_point(aes(col=Species))+
    labs(title="Lithuanian char: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪžąčęėįšųūž")

```
````

I pass the `header_lt_text.txt` with follwoing arguments:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

Any suggestions on how to make `ggplot` create correct labels?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680619/greek-letter-in-title-of-r-markdown-document

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821326/how-can-i-write-special-characters-in-rmarkdown-latex-documents

Comment: @bbiasi unfortunately, my problem does not concern the main document, but the embedded ggplot2 chart. I clear any problems in the main docckument with the header including `\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}`

Comment: Are you using Windows? R on WIndows always has problems with UTF-8 encodings.

Comment: I opened a bounty on this question, I hope to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the `pdf` device and is only apparent when saving the picture as pdf (which you want because it looks much, much better). This is why it seems to "work" in some cases: the image is not rendered as pdf but e.g. as png. Thanks to @Konrad for correctly identifying the source of the problem.

To solve this, you need to pass the correct encoding to the `pdf` device. 
Fortunately, the pdf device (`?pdf`) takes an `encoding` argument and [there is a chunk option](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots) to pass arguments to the device: `dev.args`

On Windows, an appropriate encoding is `CP1257.enc` (Baltic):

````
```{r dev="pdf", dev.args=list(encoding="CP1257.enc")}
  ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point(aes(col=Species))+
  labs(title="Lithuanian char: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪžąčęėįšųūž")
```
````

You can see the other encodings available out of the box with: `list.files(system.file("enc", package = "grDevices"))`

Works well on my linux machine:

[image: success2]

Alternatively, if you're happy to get png images inserted in the pdf, you can simply use `dev="png"` in your chunk option. Doesn't look as good though.